# Generate trend graph in excel

Tags: excel

I encountered a practical problem that can be simplified as follows:

My excel sheet has a single column which is the date I had a beer can. It can repeat based on the number of beers cans I had a day. (eg. I had three beers on 5/9/2012) I need to generate the trend of my beer consumption per week. How can I do it in excel?

```
**Date of beer**
5/9/2012
5/9/2012
5/9/2012
5/12/2012
...
7/3/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a pivot table. Date as a row field, Count of Date (i.e., count of beers) as a data field. Group the row field Date by 7 days to get weekly totals.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off with a two column spreadsheet.  Column A = Date; Column B = Number of cans.  Then you could easily just make a line graph from that.

If you already have a large amount of data in your format you can use excel's subtotal function to create the two column format for you.

Answer (score 0):

First i would put a formula in to get a week number for each date, and then use a count if for each week of the year.
This formula will assign each day of the year the week number of the year it falls in.  Put this in each cell next to your dates.

```
   =IFERROR(1+INT((AF12-DATE(YEAR(AF12+4-WEEKDAY(AF12+6)),1,5)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(AF12+4-WEEKDAY(AF12+6)),1,3)))/7),0)
```

Once that is done create a column of numbers 1-52 (53 for leap year) and do

```
   =countif(rangeofcalcdweeknumbers,week1to52)
```

and copy that down for all 52 or 53 weeks

Then make a graph based on the final two columns